# BuildFailed Error: Cannot build C++ SDK Helloworld with qibuild

Tags: c++, linux, build, cross-compiling, nao-robot

I'm trying to install NaoQI C++ SDK on Linux 18.04.1 (VirtualBox). I followed this installation instruction: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/dev/cpp/install_guide.html

My problem is in Part E. Step.3, when I'm trying to run "qibuild make"

I get this error while I'm trying to build the helloworld example:

> CMakeFiles/testhelloworld.dir/testhelloworld.cpp.o: In function
>   `main':
>   /home/nounou/Documents/SDKfolder/naoqi-sdk/doc/dev/cpp/examples/core/helloworld/testhelloworld.cpp:35:
>   undefined reference to`
>   AL::ALBroker::createBroker(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&,
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string,
>   std::allocator > const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, int, int,
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string,
>   std::allocator >, bool)'
>   /home/nounou/Documents/SDKfolder/naoqi-sdk/doc/dev/cpp/examples/core/helloworld/testhelloworld.cpp:38:
>   undefined reference to
>   `AL::ALProxy::ALProxy(boost::shared_ptr<AL::ALBroker>,
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
>   std::allocator<char> > const&, int, int)'
>   CMakeFiles/testhelloworld.dir/testhelloworld.cpp.o: In function`
>   qi::log::LogStream::~LogStream()':

....

> CMakeFiles/testhelloworld.dir/build.make:113: recipe for target
>   'sdk/bin/testhelloworld' failed make[2]: *** [sdk/bin/testhelloworld]
>   Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/testhelloworld.dir/all' failed make[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/testhelloworld.dir/all] Error 2 Makefile:129: recipe for
>   target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2
>
> [ERROR]: BuildFailed Error occurred when building project hello world

Please, help me if you have any idea about what the problem is. Thank you!

Comment: ALProxy is missing from your system, so the compiler cannot link. Either it's installed but not in a path that the compiler can find, or it's not installed. Check to see if "alcommon" library is installed.

Comment: I checked it out. The "alcommon" library is installed. How I can do that the compiler can find it?

Comment: Which version of the C++ SDK have you installed ? 2.1 ?

Comment: Listing the output of `qitoolchain info` could help figure out what is going on exactly.

Comment: I have installed the version 2.1.4.13 of the C++ SDK. I have a NAO robot V4.

Comment: @Emile   

nounou@nounou-VirtualBox:~$ qitoolchain info
Toolchain mytoolchain
Using feed from /home/nounou/Documents/SDKfolder/naoqi-sdk/toolchain.xml on master
  Packages:
  libnaoqi
   in /home/nounou/Documents/SDKfolder/naoqi-sdk

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Fedora 29... After some hours of search I found that adding  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0") to the CMakeLists.txt file fixed the problem.

I found the solution here:
[gcc using c++11 standard even though 98 explicitly specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42514202/gcc-using-c11-standard-even-though-98-explicitly-specified)

Comment: Thanks ! Worked for me. After one day trying to solve the problem (as part of many others). I am using WSL Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with a v3.3 robot. Not the best idea to use a robot old of 10 years with modern compilers ... Thank you A LOT ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have an ABI incompatibility issue, due to the transition to C++11. You are using Ubuntu 18.04, which compilers are configured to link with modern C++ libraries, but the toolchain is compiled with former ABIs, and does not enforce compiler flags to ensure compatibility.

To workaround this, either:

- Set compiler flags to make sure you don't link against C++11 libraries (if someone knows them, please share).
- Compile for the robot instead of your machine, by using the cross-toolchain instead of the Linux toolchain.
- Use Ubuntu 12.04, as told in the installation guide.

By the way, in the C++ installation guide, subsection E.4, it says to compile the example under `core/sayhelloworld`. Here you compiled the example under `core/helloworld`.